# $b_n=\dfrac{\binom{n}{a}}{\binom{n}{b}}$

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, convergence-divergence

For, $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$, consider the sequence $$b_n=\dfrac{\binom{n}{a}}{\binom{n}{b}}$$
for $n>a,b$. Then, show that as $n\to\infty$, the sequence $\{b_n\}$ converges if $a\leq b$.

The equality part is obvious. But the problem I am facing in the "$<$" part. Noting that $a<\dfrac{n}{2}<b$, since it is possible that $\binom{n}{a}>\binom{n}{b}$, how can I argue the convergence? Please help!

Comment: Notice that $n\choose a$ is a polynomial in $n$, of degree $a$.

Comment: You only care about what happens for large $n$ for convergence.  Then if $a \lt b, {n \choose a} \lt {n \choose b}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\binom{n}{a}}{\binom{n}{b}}=\frac{b!}{a!}\cdot\frac{n\times(n-1)\times\cdots\times(n-a+1)}{n\times(n-1)\times\cdots\times(n-b+1)}$$
If $a>b$, then the number of terms in the numerator of the second term in the rhs, is more than the number of terms in its denominator and the sequence will diverge to $+\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. If $a<b$, then the number of terms in the denominator is larger and if we divide both the denominator and numerator by $n^b$, then the denominator goes to $1$ and the numerator goes to $0$, which implies the sequence has limit $0$.

Comment: thanks ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Sorry there was a typo. I edited the answer.